# How find a twin prime number from a range determined by the user in Fortran

Tags: fortran, primes

I want to make a program that finds twin prime numbers in a certain range, from n to m. Here it is what I have so far:

```
             program twin
                 implicit none
                 integer  i, count1, n, m, count2, j, k, pri1, pri2
                 count1 = 0
                 count2 = 0
                 read(5,*)n
                 read(5,*)m
                 do i = 1,m
                    do j = n,m
                    if (mod(j,i) ==0) then
                         count1 = count1 +1
                    else
                         count1 = count1
                         if(count1 ==0) then
                            pri1 = j
                            do k=j,m
                            if (mod(k,i)==0) then
                               count2 = count2 +1
                            else
                               count2 = count2
                               if(count2 ==0) then
                                 pri2 = k
                                 if (pri2-pri1 == 2) then
                                     write(*,*)j,k
                                 end if
                               end if
                            end if
                            end do
                         end if
                     end if
                     end do
                 end do
             end program twin
```

I tried n = 4 and m = 8, expecting to get 5 and 7, the n = 70 and m = 74, wanting 71 and 73, but in both cases it doesn't return nothing, why is that?

Comment: What output do you get? Why is it wrong? Off the top of my head, it looks like you're not initializing `count1` and `count2` to be 0.

Comment: Why do you think it does not work? What does it do?

Comment: Except for (3, 5) all twin primes are of the form (6n-1, 6n+1).

Comment: @LíviaDantas for codes such as this, it helps to write out your loops by hand. You know for the example of 2 and 5 that you should only output 3 and 5. Breaking down your problem into smaller chunks can also help. By pulling out the checking for a prime, you can be more confident your larger code works, when you are confident your small sections of code work. This is basic idea behind unit testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to rewrite your code using a function call. I always try to use functions and subroutines as much as possible when there is repeated code. In this case, the check to see if the integer was a prime is an obvious choice.

I also reduced the loops to only look at numbers between `m` and `n` (I swapped them round because I'm funny like that) and once a prime has been found between that number and `n`.

```
program twin

  implicit none

  integer :: m, n, i, j, prime1, prime2

  read(*,*)m
  read(*,*)n

  do i = m, n 
     if (is_prime(i)) then
        prime1 = i
        do j = i, n
           if (is_prime(j)) then
              prime2 = j
              if (prime2-prime1 == 2) then
                 write(*,*)i, j
              end if
           end if
        end do
     end if
  end do

contains

  function is_prime(num) result(output)
    implicit none
    integer, intent(in) :: num
    logical :: output
    integer :: i
    integer :: count

    count = 0

    if (num > 1) then
       do i = 2, num-1
          if (mod(num, i) == 0) then
             count = count + 1
          end if
       end do
    else
       count = count + 1
    end if

    if (count .eq. 0) then
       output = .true.
    else
       output = .false.
    end if

  end function is_prime

end program twin
```

There are several issues with the original code, the count variables are not reinitialized for each loop. Once this is fixed, there are problems when checking for a prime number. I have found it impossible, thus far, to maintain the original structure and return only genuine prime numbers. Problems arise from the `mod(j, i)` check. When `i > j`, the code returns `j` as a prime. When all `i` are not common factors of `j`, it returns a prime.

```
program twin
  implicit none
  integer  i, count1, n, m, count2, j, k, pri1, pri2
  count1 = 0
  count2 = 0
  pri1 = 0
  pri2 = 0
  read(5,*)n
  read(5,*)m
  do i = n, m
     count1 = 0
     do j = 2, i - 1
        if (mod(i, j) == 0) then
           count1 = count1 + 1
        else
           count1 = count1
        end if
     end do
     if (count1 == 0) then
        pri1 = i
        do k = i, m
           count2 = 0
           do j = 2, k - 1
              if (mod(k, j) == 0) then
                 count2 = count2 + 1
              else
                 count2 = count2
              end if
           end do
           if (count2 == 0) then
              pri2 = k
              if (pri2 - pri1 == 2) then
                 write(*,*) pri1, pri2
              end if
           end if
        end do
     end if
  end do

end program twin
```

Comment: I think you should also explain what is wrong with the initial code

Comment: @Ross I have added a small comment.

Comment: It worked, thank you. But I still don't know how to work with subroutines and functions, could you please explain what was wrong with my code?

Comment: @LíviaDantas I have added a version without the function call.

Comment: @muddle thanks, I'll practice more so those mistakes don't happen again